# Call value of a variable in one m file into another m file

Tags: matlab

I have an m-file named motor_model.m. I have another m-file named controller.m where I am calling motor_model.m in the first line. Now the output of motor_model.m is the steady state current, which is stored in a variable named I_steadystate whose value needs to be called in controller.m.

Could you give me the code as to how I can do this?

Comment: Are these script files or functions?

Comment: Script Files. What do I do?

Comment: In script files, you don't need to do anything.  Just use the variable by name as if everything were in one file.

Answer (score 0):

In the m file controller.m:

```
function [] = controller()
steadyState = motor_model()
```

In the m file motor_model.m

```
function [I_steadystate] = motor_model()
I_steadystate = 0; % 0 is an example. I_steadyState should be defined somewhere in your code.
```

Comment: Does that require me the call motor_model.m in controller.m

Comment: Yes, but you already said that you do that on the first line anyway... This does, however, turn your scripts into [functions](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/function.html) (See also [this](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/scripts-and-functions.html)).